# Why does not C# support operator overloading with pass by reference?

Tags: c#, clr, c++-cli, operator-overloading, command-line-interface

Is this a CLR restriction or a language design decision? I tried to do it in C++/CLI, of course where it works because the need to support native c++:

```
public ref class Test
    {
        public:
        static Test^ operator &( Test^ msg, int& i )
        {
            i = i + 1;

            return nullptr;
        } 
    };
```

and then looked at the compiler omitted output:

```
public: static Test __gc* op_BitwiseAnd(Test __gc* msg, Int32 __gc** modopt(IsImplicitlyDereferenced __gc*) i)
{
    i[0] += 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I went further and tried to call this operator from C# project - and of course I needed to go [unsafe] to do it( I needed pointer ):

```
Test t = new Test();
int i = 0;

unsafe
{
    t = t & &i;
}
```

Obviously not so hard to implement for the CLR? I really miss pass by reference in operators overloading and would like to at least in light myself in why is this missing?

Why can't C# hide the ugliness behind the unsafe and pointers when we need to deal with reference variables in our operator overloads? Even if I chose to go with this ugly workaround it wouldn't work in Silverlight, where unsafe operations is not allowed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, your variables are never altered by callees without you explicitly passing them as references (e.g. `int.TryParse(s, out i)` where you explicitly specify the `out` keyword). This feature would make things complicated by allowing the overloaded operator alter the contents of the operands without your explicit permission.

For instance,

```
public static MyStruct operator + (ref MyStruct left, ref MyStruct right) {
    left = new MyStruct(); // !!!!!!!!
    return something(left, right);
}
```

When you reference such an operator in C#:

```
MyStruct x = new MyStruct();
MyStruct y = new MyStruct();
MyStruct z = x + y; // in C#, you never expect `x` to be changed.
```

Comment: Not at all. Just make operator overloading to take ref parameter?

Comment: Ivan: then how you'd call the overloaded operator? If a method takes a `ref` parameter, the call site **and** the definition site should **explicitly** declare the parameter as `ref`.

Comment: Mehrdad: This is perfectly OK. They have different signature, so calling without ref will never match a ref overload. What is so complicated about that, that made C# team not implement it? What if I really need to alter a operand that is not a reference type - how do I do it?

Comment: You could use z = x + (ref y); I suppose. But to what end? Operators should be combining values, not mutating them.

Comment: Ivan: C# is designed not to clone C++ complexities. "What if I really need to alter a operand that is not a reference type - how do I do it?" First, if you **really** need it, you should create a method, not an operator for that purpose. You are abusing operator overloading. Second, what if the callee isn't conscious of your decision and suddenly sees his variable modified in an expression? This will cause headaches in debugging.

Comment: "What if I really need to alter a operand that is not a reference type - how do I do it?" Use a method instead. I don't think there is ever a situation where you *really* need an operator, specifically, that works this way.

Comment: My last comment: s/callee/caller

Comment: @Ivan: I think you are missing the point that is trying to be made. C# has a set of fundamental, core rules, one of which is that operators will never modify the references it operates on. It is a useful and appropriate rule, in my opinion, and the C++ behavior can lead to bugs that are very hard to identify and track down. Given your C++/CLI implementation, I would have been very confused by its behavior if I had ever encountered it without knowing the implementation.

Comment: Joren: You're wrong. There are plenty, and if you look at boost c++ library you will find great techniques that can be done as well in C#. But I don't want to get into details, too much to explain. I just needed to reason myself why this operator overloading is left out.

Comment: Ivan: Designing a language involves a bunch of trade offs. C# puts "simplicity" high in its list of design goals. It's not a matter of technical possibility. Sure, it's possible. C++ is the existence proof. With the same reasoning you can argue why Java does not have operator overloading at all. Because the designers thought for accomplishing the design goals of Java, the benefits do not outweigh the costs and the increased complexity.

Comment: @Ivan: C# is not C++, and as a matter of fact, it specifically aims to plug some of the loopholes in C++ that can lead to excessively convoluted behavior and unexpected memory modification. I think this is a supreme example of WHY C# doesn't allow ref-modifying operators and similar things. Don't assume that C# == (C++ + extra). C# only inherits C++ structure and basic syntax, not all of its behavior, and appropriately so.

Comment: Allowing types to override things like `+=` with a method whose first parameter was a `ref` type would yielded semantics entirely in line with expectations, but would have allowed certain types to implement such operators in a fashion which was more efficient or offered better thread safety than would be possible as the `+=` operator is normally implemented.

Comment: I'd have to agree that this could be inlined in a predictable way and would definitely have benefits. Prime example: operator overloading on user-defined matrix types for use in a graphics application. A 4x4 matrix is a bombshell to pass around by value at each call, which is why we often resort to creating function calls that make use of pass-by-ref functionality even for methods such as equality comparisons where we have no intentions of allowing either operand to be changed. Allowing the same semantics for operator overloading would be wonderful for this.

Comment: C# really needs a form of "const" (aka immutable variable, though which can't be casted away), then an operator could take a "const ref" and get the performance benefit of passing a pointer while knowing the data is still immutable.

Comment: @jrista That seems to be ignoring that fact that `++` and `--` operators exist in C#, and can be overloaded, and should logically take a `ref` implicitly as they do in the normal language.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because an operator (in the more mathematical view that C# seems to take) is logically something that combines its arguments into a new value, never supposed to be mutating anything. C++ seems to consider operators more as a version of general operations with more convenient syntax than functions, than as a way to represent maths in particular. I think that in C# you'll almost never see things like defining operators for stream operations and such.

Comment: C# has `++` and `--` operators that make this entire line of argument questionable.